# How can I get the response of an html form after submit?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit

I have a form with the action like so:

```
<form id="my_form" method="post" action="http://xxxx/post.do">
```

The service that receives the form data performs validation and then returns a response.  What is the easiest way to do this?  I have seen various posts about AJAX that I cannot get to work and I don't necessarily need to submit without refreshing.  I just want the simplest solution in pure html/javascript where i can retrieve the server response after submission.

Comment: If you don't use AJAX, the page reloads with the response that the server sends, which should be HTML.

Comment: If you want to get the response in Javascript, you have to use AJAX. I suggest you read a tutorial on it and try to get it to work.

Comment: Please share your javascript as well

Comment: You can look at XMLHttpRequest() https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp